# compare empty array to any scalar will get an empty array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
In [2]: a = np.random.random(4)
In [3]: a
Out[3]: array([0.87932117, 0.77583433, 0.82855167, 0.52718255])

In [4]: empty = a[4:]

In [5]: empty
Out[5]: array([], dtype=float64)

In [9]: normal = a[0]

In [10]: normal
Out[10]: 0.879321173826548

In [11]: bigger = np.maximum(empty, normal)

In [12]: bigger
Out[12]: array([], dtype=float64)
```

my code is shown above. I get an empty array `empty` and an normal array `normal`, then I use the `np.maximum()` function to find the Element-wise maximum of array elements `bigger`.

I am curious I get the result is an `empty`?

Comment: Your `normal` is a scalar (a single number), not an array.  `normal = a[:1]` would give you an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to happen because `numpy.maximum` is not returning the larger array, but compares element-wise and returns an array with the maximum for each, see here:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.maximum.html

So in you example, since there were no elements to compare in `empty`, `numpy.maximum` returned exactly that - an empty array.

Answer (score 2):

According to Numpy documentation [`numpy.maximum`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/) compares two arrays and returns a new array containing the element-wise maxima. It works only if the arrays have the same size or if one or both of the arguments are scalars.

With an empty array you have nothing to compare so the function returns an empty array.

Comment: It will also work if the array shapes are different, if they can be broadcast to a single shape.

Answer (score 0):

I have edited the question title. As PM 2Ring pointed,  my `normal` is just a scalar. 
In fact, when using an empty array to compare with a normal array, it will result in **Error**:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (0,) (..normal.shape)
```